# Samba, hosts allow = .example.com

Tags: samba

I'm trying to limit access to a Samba share to hosts on the .example.com domain. But when I try to connect from a host on that domain I get denied.

smb.conf

```
[share1]
...
valid users = ralph
hosts allow = .example.com
```

Samba log

```
check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [ralph] -> [ralph] -> [ralph] succeeded
Denied connection from 10.234.56.1 (10.234.56.1)
```

There is a reverse DNS record in place for that IP address. That leaves me wondering if the Samba server is actually checking the reverse record to see if the host is on that domain.

If I remove the hosts allow statement the share works as expected. I have restarted the nmb service every time I restarted the smb service.

Which component is responsible for performing the PTR record lookup?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: I included the samba log output in the question. Is there another log that would be of interest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for host allow entries using hostnames to work you need to enable

```
hostname lookups = yes
```

In the global configuration of smb.conf.

None of the WINS settings were required for me to get this working. Testing with the nmb service disabled the share continued to work.

Answer (score 2):

The DNS resolving does not seem to work. Add the first three triplets instead of a domain as the `hosts allow`:

`hosts allow = 10.234.56`

restart samba and try again to login.

If DNS needs to be used then some additional configuration is required in Samba:

[**7.3.4.4 dns proxy**](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch07_03.html)

```
If you want the domain name service (DNS) to be used if a name isn't found in WINS, you can
set the following option:

[global]
    dns proxy = yes
```

Also check the following:

[**7.3.4.5 name resolve order**](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch07_03.html)

```
The global name resolve order option specifies the order of services that Samba will use
in attempting name resolution. The default order is to use the LMHOSTS file, followed by
standard Unix name resolution methods (some combination of /etc/hosts, DNS, and NIS), then 
query a WINS server, and finally use broadcasting to determine the address of a NetBIOS name.
You can override this option by specifying something like the following:

[global]
    name resolve order = lmhosts wins hosts bcast
```

Comment: This works for the specific test, but I need to make it work based on the hostname .example.com

Comment: DNS resolution seems fine, forward and backward. If I `dig -x 10.234.56.1` I get the answer of `1.56.234.10.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN      PTR     host.example.com.` from the same system that is hosting the share.

Comment: No, but I just tried and got the same error. The Samba docs are pretty clear on the leading '.' syntax so I didn't think to change it.

Comment: @xdaxdb I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks but that is not working.